# Get element height in JS or jQuery with CSS height: 0;

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I'm trying to get their height of an element, but the height is set with css to:

```
height: 0;
```

So when I log the console I get a height of 0, but I want to get the real height of the element.

I have also tried:

```
$('nav').prop('scrollHeight');
```

as someone suggested, but the height it gave me was a bit off.

My HTML markup is very simple"

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li>
text 1
</li>
<li>
text 2
</li>
<li>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS is:

```
nav {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if the height is set to 0, what you meant by real height?

Comment: How is the element visible with `height: 0`? I know some possibilities, but can you show the HTML/CSS extract of your actual case?

Comment: It's not visible with height: 0; in CSS. I'm trying to get the height as if it were set to auto;

Comment: Please add your html markup as well.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough, can you explain more

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the default height of a block that is currently `height: 0` then try:

```
document.getElementById("blockid").scrollHeight
```

It should return the correct value unless you're messing something up.